# Show that $F$ preserves direct limits (resp. inverse limits)

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, limits-colimits

I am trying to prove the next results,

*Let $F: {}_{R}\mathfrak{M}\longrightarrow {}_{S}\mathfrak{M}$ a covariant funtor (between $R$-modules and $S$-modules categories). Suposse that such functor is left exact  and it preserves direct limits. Show it preserves inverse limits.*

and the "dual" assertion,

*Let $F: {}_{R}\mathfrak{M}\longrightarrow {}_{S}\mathfrak{M}$ a covariant functor. Suposse that such functor is left exact  and it turns coproducts into products. Show it turns direct limits into inverse limits.*

I'm not able to use morita's theorems, so I was trying to give a direct proof of this, but I don't fin any conection between direct limits and inverse limits in this case, in the same case, I was trying to do something like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508781/left-exact-preserve-product). Any hint?

Comment: The first one isn't true : take $R=S=\mathbb{Z}$, and $F= -\otimes \mathbb{Q}$. Since $F$ is left adjoint to $\hom_R (\mathbb{Q}, -)$, it preserves all colimits, in particular direct limits. Moreover, $\mathbb{Q}$ being flat, it is exact, so left exact. But now if you look at, say $\mathbb{Z}_p = \varprojlim_n \mathbb{Z/p^nZ}$ you can see that $F$ doesn't preserve inverse limits

Comment: And you should be a bit more precise when you say "turns coproducts into products"  : we have a precise notion of preserving limits, but here you're going from a limit to a colimit so how are the structure arrows transformed ?

Comment: When I say that "turns coproducts into products" I mean that $F\left(\amalg_{i}M_i\right)\cong \prod_{i} F(M_i)$, and thank you for your help!, I just have a doubt, obviously $\varprojlim_n (\mathbb{Z/p^nZ}\otimes \mathbb{Q})=0$, but how can I show that $\mathbb{Z}_{p}\otimes \mathbb{Q} \neq 0$? Once more, thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok so you don't require anything about the structure arrows. For $\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ you can study more generally for a commutative ring $R$ and a multiplicatively closed set $S\subset R$ what $M\otimes_R (S^{-1}R)$ is, for $M$ an $R$-module; and this should help you see why it's not $0$ here